# Apply a function to a value inside IO Maybe

Tags: haskell

I have a function of type `a -> IO (Maybe b)` and I want to apply it to `IO (Maybe a)` and get `IO (Maybe b)`. I wrote a function to do that:

```
ioMaybeApply :: (a -> IO (Maybe b)) -> IO (Maybe a) -> IO (Maybe b)
ioMaybeApply f ioMaybeA = do
  maybeA <- ioMaybeA
  maybe (return Nothing) f maybeA
```

Is there a standard Haskell function to do that? I tried searching with Hoogle but I didn't find anything. If not, is my implementation good, or could it be simpler?

Comment: But `maybe :: b -> (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> b` is not an `IO` monad?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem In my code `maybe` returns either `return Nothing` (which is of type `IO (Maybe b)`) or the return value of `f` (which also is `IO (Maybe b)`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be achieved through the [`MaybeT` monad transformer](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.4.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Maybe.html):

```
GHCi> import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe
GHCi> :t \f m -> runMaybeT (MaybeT m >>= MaybeT . f)
\f m -> runMaybeT (MaybeT m >>= MaybeT . f)
  :: Monad m => (a1 -> m (Maybe a)) -> m (Maybe a1) -> m (Maybe a)
```

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe

-- Making it look like your definition, for the sake of comparison.
ioMaybeApply :: (a -> IO (Maybe b)) -> IO (Maybe a) -> IO (Maybe b)
ioMaybeApply f ioMaybeA = runMaybeT $ do
  a <- MaybeT ioMaybeA
  MaybeT (f a)
```

If you are using this pattern in multiple places, it will likely pay off to change your `a -> IO (Maybe b)` functions to `a -> MaybeT IO b` -- then you can just use `(>>=)` and/or seamless do-blocks instead of your special-purpose function. On the other hand, if this is just an one-off you may reasonably think that using `MaybeT` would be overkill; in that case, your implementation is perfectly fine.

(It is worth mentioning that while there is a general-purpose wrapper for nested functors called [`Compose`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Functor-Compose.html) that has `Functor` and `Applicative` instances, it doesn't have a `Monad` instance, as nesting two monads doesn't necessarily result in something that can be given a legal `Monad` instance. That being so, we typically resort to monad transformers tailored for each combination that works.)

Comment: In cases where `MaybeT` is overkill: you can sometimes use `(fmap . fmap)`

Comment: @JeremyList Yup. (Note for other readers: in this case, that amounts to a hand-written equivalent of `fmap` for `MaybeT IO` (or `Compose IO Maybe`), just like Michał's `ioMaybeApply` is a hand-written equivalent of `(>>=)` for `MaybeT IO`.)